# How can I execute custom code when the AOT Service Starts on the Server in MS Dynamics AX?

Tags: axapta, x++

I need to switch off certain some batch jobs when DAX has been restarted. How can I accomplish this?

Note from Author: This is most likely a X++ programming question and not configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your instructions in `Application.startupPost()`:

```
if (new Session().clientKind() == ClientType::Server)
{
   this.fuzzyTheBatchJobs();
}
```

Comment: I have not this myself, only in the context of ClientType::Client.

Comment: Another place could be `SysStartupCmdBatchRun.infoRun()` which is executed if you start your batch with a command line option -startcmd=Batch.